# Testing a Redux action creator that appends a timestamp

Tags: mocha.js, momentjs, sinon, redux

When writing a Mocha test spec against an action creator how can I be certain what a timestamp will be if it is generated within the action creator?

It doesn't have to utilize Sinon, but I tried to make use of [Sinon Fake Timers](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock) to "freeze time" and just can't seem to get this pieced together wither with my limited knowledge of stubbing and mocking.  If this is considered a Redux anti-pattern please point me in a better direction, but my understanding is that Redux action creators can be non-pure functions, unlike reducers.

Borrowing a little from the [Redux Writing Tests Recipes](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) here is the core of my problem as I understand it...

**CommonUtils.js**

```
import moment from 'moment';

export const getTimestamp = function () {
  return moment().format();
};
```

**TodoActions.js**

```
import { getTimestamp } from '../../utils/CommonUtils';    

export function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    text,
    timestamp: getTimestamp() // <-- This is the new property
  };
};
```

**TodoActions.spec.js**

```
import expect from 'expect';
import * as actions from '../../actions/TodoActions';
import * as types from '../../constants/ActionTypes';
import { getTimestamp } from '../../utils/CommonUtils';

describe('actions', () => {
  it('should create an action to add a todo', () => {
    const text = 'Finish docs';
    const timestamp = getTimestamp(); // <-- This will often be off by a few milliseconds
    const expectedAction = {
      type: types.ADD_TODO,
      text,
      timestamp
    };
    expect(actions.addTodo(text)).toEqual(expectedAction);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing time I have used this library successfully in the past: https://www.npmjs.com/package/timekeeper

Then in a beforeEach and afterEach you can save the time to be something specific and make your assertions then reset the time to be normal after.

```
  let time;
  beforeEach(() => {
    time = new Date(1451935054510); // 1/4/16
    tk.freeze(time);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    tk.reset();
  });
```

Now you can make assertions on what time is being returned.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I used **timeKeeper**, its very simple and easy to use, compared to **proxyquire**

Answer (score 0):

I would still love to see other answers but I finally got a reasonable solution.  This answer uses [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to override/replace the *getTimestamp()* method defined in *CommonUtils* when used by *TodoActions* for the duration of the test.

No modifications to *CommonUtils.js* or *TodoActions.js* from above:

**TodoActions.spec.js**

```
import expect from 'expect';
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
import * as types from '../../constants/ActionTypes';

const now = '2016-01-06T15:30:00-05:00';
const commonStub = {'getTimestamp': () => now};
const actions = proxyquire('../../actions/TodoActions', {
    '../../utils/CommonUtils': commonStub
});

describe('actions', () => {
  it('should create an action to add a todo', () => {
    const text = 'Finish docs';
    const timestamp = now; // <-- Use the variable defined above
    const expectedAction = {
      type: types.ADD_TODO,
      text,
      timestamp
    };
    expect(actions.addTodo(text)).toEqual(expectedAction);
  });
});
```